# Postgres- Golang- Schema vs Database ?

Tags: database, postgresql, go, schema

I am using golang and Postgres for my application. In my application, For new user am creating new database and tables for that user.So for Each and every new customer, am creating new database. while processing in my application, am going to make too many connection to connect particular user database..This is now currently am doing. My Question is , Whether i have to create schema for new user instead of databases in postgres, to reduce connection. In this case, Only one database is created under the database,too many schema will created. This is best way or not.

Comment: I dont know what is Goland, but creating a database for each user is the crazy thing I hear in a while. Just add a field `user_id` to each relevant table

Comment: Looks like you have a serious design problem.

Comment: Just in case wasnt clear, create one schema for user also bad idea. So the answer is neither.

Comment: http://scn.sap.com/community/cloud/blog/2015/07/12/multi-tenant-vs-single-tenant-architecture-saas

Comment: Have to maintain each user details, that why creating separate database for customer. Database contains more than 50 tables. So i need unique database for each customer.

Comment: Yes, that is why you add `user_id` field  to each of those 50 table instead of create 50 tables for each user

Answer (score 0):

If the schema for each customer is different then you should use Event Based data storage, in which instead of creating columns for every field create rows.

Each row in this case consists of 4 fixed columns:
**id** (unique for each entry), **res_id**(points to its parent **id** field if present), **key** (ex-"user_id"), **value** (ex-"1").